# RDBMS setup itself with Application installation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, rdbms

I want to know is there any RDBMS which will install with our application executable file & we'll don't need to setup Database in every single machine, Like user just install the app and run RDBMS will also setup it self in installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is more to that, than meets the eye: The first question to answer is, whether the RDBMS is used **concurrently**.

- If not, a simple file-based engine will most likely be sufficient: I recomment SQlite, as it is as cross-platform as can be. There is no setup involved, you can simply package the sqlite.[so|dll|dylib] with your application
- If yes, you have to think about which installation should be the "master" installation, with others being slaves: It might not be a good idea to use a salesman's laptop as the master, even if it happens this is the first machine available. Decicated servers exist for a reason. A lot of products have an installer, that asks for an installation mode such as Standalone/Server/Client. Chosing Server will mostly result in calling the installer for the RDBMS first.

My personal opinion is: If a non-tivial app is multitiered like in the second bullet, the tiers should be installed one-by-one by someone, who has an idea, what these tiers are and do. If not, you create an accident waiting to happen. But again - this is my personal opinion only.